# Working with data from observable in a component in Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, http, crud, angular2-observables

I am not sure if I have phrased this question correctly, so I apologize for the clunky wording. I am relatively new to angular but am pretty comfortable with making HTTP requests and working with the data in other frameworks (like VueJS). I am beginning to understand the **Observables** that angular uses. I am trying to make a blog application, and have an express backend that has the `JSON` for the blog posts.

In my **`post.service.ts`** I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Post } from '../post';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PostService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/posts';

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }

constructor( private http: HttpClient,
  private postService: PostService ) { }

}
```

And then I want to list all the posts in my **`post-list.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service'
import { Post } from '../../post';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})

export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  public posts = [];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts()
      .subscribe(data => this.posts = data);
  }
}
```

But the posts array becomes an object and i'm not sure how to use it as an array. If I try to use the `*ngFor` method, I get an error. The page shows [object Object] if I put `{{posts}}` in the html. If i do `{{posts | json}}` it shows the actual `JSON`, but I still cannot iterate through it.

This is what the json looks like:

```
{
    "posts": [
    {
        "_id": "5b04b269fde3ca29b35ffc3e",
        "name": "Mike",
        "title": "Stuff",
        "post": "This is a post about stuff"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b04b24dfde3ca29b35ffc3d",
        "name": "OtherUser",
        "title": "New Post Test",
        "post": "This is a test post"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b02ed783aa641758c08e601",
        "name": "Emerjawn",
        "title": "Post"
    }
    ]
}
```

Before I try to setup CRUD for this application, I want to simply figure out how to display the data which I still cannot do and it is driving me insane. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: try `this.posts = data.posts`

Answer (score 1):

Your return JSON is an object which has `field` **posts** holding your needed **array data** so just take `posts` field from your server response and render such array of posts. Something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts()
      .subscribe(data => this.posts = data.posts);
  }
```

For better typing you can always specify your variable type i.e. `public posts: Post[]` then you will have type checking while coding.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately changing posts to data.posts gives the error, ` Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'Post[]'." `

Comment: That error is part of type checking. As you know and ensure that response data is an array of Post type, then you can **cast** your data in such type. Something like this: data => this posts = <Post[]> data.posts

Comment: No, the problem with the current typing is that the http request response is incorrectly typed to Post[] already.

Comment: @IngoBürk this solved it, thank you! I changed the Observable in the getPosts() function to type <any>. I am wondering if there is any point of using the observable at all, from what I gather it is just something that the new versions of Angular use (I am using Angular 6).

Comment: @E.Max I as your http request is **asynchronous** in nature, Observable implementation is needed.

Comment: @E.Max you typed the request to return `<Post[]>` but it actually returns `<{ posts: Post[]; }>`, try that instead of `<any>`.